# How to use Porkbun SSL Certificate Files with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Porkbun Let's Encrypt Files with Nginx.
They have generated a zip file with the following files for me to use
*domain.cert.pem*, *intermediate.cert.pem*, *private.key.pem*, *public.key.pem*

From this site https://wbxpress.net/install-porkbun-ssl-nginx-wordpress/
I've worked out that
`ssl_certificate` is *domain.cert.pem*
`ssl_certificate_key` is *private.cert.pem*

But for my needs I have to specify the `ssl_trusted_certificate` as well.
Can anybody point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you used the certbot you will get these files: `README` `cert.pem`  `chain.pem`  `fullchain.pem`  `privkey.pem`

- `ssl_certificate` should point to `fullchain.pem`
- `ssl_certificate_key` should point to `privkey.pem`
- `ssl_trusted_certificate` should point to `chain.pem`

From what I see, the PorkBun generated files are just renamed and mapped like this:

- `fullchain.pem` -> `domain.cert.pem`
- `privkey.pem` -> `private.key.pem`
- `chain.pem` -> `intermediate.cert.pem`
- `cert.pem` -> `public.key.pem`

So you would do this for the files given by PorkBun:

- `ssl_certificate` should point to `domain.cert.pem`
- `ssl_certificate_key` should point to `private.key.pem`
- `ssl_trusted_certificate` should point to `intermediate.cert.pem`

Basically `fullchain.pem` is just made up of `cert.pem` + `chain.pem` concatenated together. See here for more information: [Generate CRT & KEY ssl files from Let's Encrypt from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389883/generate-crt-key-ssl-files-from-lets-encrypt-from-scratch)

Personally, I would *not* use their generated ones because you would have to manually replace it every 90 days. Best if you use another option like [certbot](https://github.com/certbot/certbot) which lets you automatically renew it or do it 'manually' via some cronjob. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. certbot seems simple enough. The instructions I was following was a bit convoluted.